# War Card Game in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating War the card game in VBA Excel. My code picks a random number from the first column then picks a random number from the second column and if the first is greater than the second then those two numbers are added to the end of the first column, otherwise they're added to the second. My problem is what happens when the numbers are equal. What I want it to do is play another card and repeat the process, then those four numbers are added to the winner's column. This is easy to do, I just repeat the same code. However, the trouble is when this happens multiple times and I need to add the cards to the winner's column dynamically. Here's the code so far:

```
Private Sub Play_Click()

Dim P1LR As Long
Dim P2LR As Long
Dim P1Cards As Long
Dim P2Cards As Long
Dim P1Random As Long
Dim P2Random As Long
Dim P1SecondRan As Long
Dim P2SecondRan As Long
Dim P1Capture As Long
Dim P1Play As Long
Dim P2Play As Long

P1LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
P2LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

P1Cards = Range("A2:P1LR")
P2Cards = Range("B2:P2LR")

P1Random = Rnd("P1Cards")
P2Random = Rnd("P2Cards")

Range("G2").Value = P1Random
Range("H2").Value = P2Random

If P1Random > P2Random Then

    Cells(P1LR + 1).Value = P1Random
    Cells(P1LR + 2).Value = P2Random

ElseIf P2Random > P1Random Then

    Cells(P2LR + 1).Value = P1Random
    Cells(P2LR + 2).Value = P2Random

ElseIf P1Random = P2Random Then

    P1SecondRan = Rnd("P1Cards")
    P2SecondRan = Rnd("P2Cards")
    
    If P1SecondRan > P2SecondRan Then
        
        

End Sub
```

Comment: Does that code actually run?

Comment: @TimWilliams it's not finished but it runs.

Comment: `Range("A2:P1LR")` runs?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it, using a Collection to store the values between plays if needed.

```vb
Private Sub Play_Click()
    
    Static picks As Collection 'keeps values between calls
    Dim P1, P2, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    If picks Is Nothing Then Set picks = New Collection
    
    P1 = RandomPick(ws.Range("A2"))
    picks.Add P1
    Range("G2").Value = P1
    
    P2 = RandomPick(ws.Range("B2"))
    picks.Add P2
    Range("H2").Value = P2
    
    If P1 > P2 Then
        AddPicks picks, ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    ElseIf P2 > P1 Then
        AddPicks picks, ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Else
        ' if values are equal then values are still in the collection
        ' and will be added to the next "winner"
        Debug.Print "matched"
    End If
    
    
End Sub

'pick a random cell value from a column
Function RandomPick(c As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = c.Parent.Range(c, c.Parent.Cells(Rows.Count, c.Column).End(xlUp))
    RandomPick = rng.Cells(Application.RandBetween(1, 4)).Value
End Function

'put the picks in a column, starting at `startCell`
Sub AddPicks(picks As Collection, startCell As Range)
    Dim v
    For Each v In picks
        startCell.Value = v
        Set startCell = startCell.Offset(1, 0)
    Next v
    Set picks = New Collection 'clear out collection
End Sub
```